# Override SHIFT + CTRL + Z in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

Hello I use Notepad++ for a lot of my development.
One of the things that I do not like about it is the way you perform a redo by pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>Y</kbd> and when you press <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd> you get `sub`

Is there a plugin or a way to override the <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd> hotkey in developing a plugin for notepad++ to make it perform the redo instead of the <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>Y</kbd>?

Now I'm not trying to criticize the design choice for this, it's just that my fingers are short and fat and I have trouble pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd> and <kbd>Y</kbd> at the same time.

Comment: Are you kidding? I need to type `sub` all the time and I never hit `ctrl-z` accidentally and if I did my fingers are so abnormally long `ctrl-y` is actually very comfortable :P

Comment: The 'Sub' ([substitute](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitute_character)) character is (or was) used as an end of file marker. You can still see it when you use a Windows command line command like `copy *.txt test.txt`. That command will combine all txt files in the current directory into a single file called `test.txt`, and end the file with a `sub` character.

Comment: You may not be trying to criticize, but I am. The default behavior of Notepad++ for Ctrl-Z is totally unacceptable! This needs to be fixed.

Comment: Notepad++ hereby commits one of the biggest crimes of UX:  don't destroy work.  So I share @Joe's anger. For example, I may undo a long chain of revisions to recover an inadvertent delete. Then if I type the wrong REDO key, **the redo chain is lost forever**.  All my revisions are gone. This gets worse when switching between editing environments. JetBrains uses Ctrl+Shift+Z for redo.  And though it pains me to laud Microsoft, VisualStudio nobly uses [both](http://visualstudioshortcuts.com/2013/) Ctrl-Y and Ctrl+Shift+Z.  Notepad++ shamefully punishes familiarity with the more common standard.

Comment: [Feature request](https://github.com/notepad-plus-plus/notepad-plus-plus/issues/856) on GitHub to **support both**.

Comment: What's horrible about this is that typing "sub" with ctrl-shift-z *throws away the entire undo stack*! The very thing you were trying to retrieve by redo-ing is now permanently lost.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

You could try the 'shortcut mapper' under the Settings menu.

It seems that this key is not found in the normal Main menu commands, but it's the SCI_REDO command in the Scintalla tab. Whatever that may mean. ;)

Comment: Wow, haha, exactly what I need. I should have seen that! Thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: It seems that this key is not found in the normal Main menu commands, but it's the SCI_REDO command in the Scintalla tab. Whatever that may mean. ;)

Comment: Thanks! This was driving me nuts. I just got a Mac and my brain has been able to handle the change from Ctrl to Command (and I can even switch between them) but having Ctrl+Shift+Z kill my redo-history (by typing some strange character) is very bad.

Comment: Killing redo history with a SUB character (ASCII 026, ALT+026 on numpad) after using undo too far back, was a nightmare until now. Thanks.

Comment: In all my npp years, putting Redo on the "Scintalla" (not Main) tab and calling it SCI_REDO is the first time I've questioned the app.  Come on npp, you're better than that...

Comment: In case anyone's interested, it seems Scintilla is the library that Notepad++ is based on: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scintilla_(software)

Answer (score 16):

**Note: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> is now natively supported by the current version of Notepad++. Just update to the newest version and you shouldn't need the instructions below.**

---

To clarify [GolezTrol's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6297954/775283), here's the exact instructions:

1. Menu bar *Settings* > *Shortcut mapper*
2. *Scintilla commands* tab > double click *SCI_REDO* in the list
3. Tick *Shift* and select *Z* from the dropdown > click *Apply* and *OK*
4. Click *Close* on the *Shortcut mapper* window.